# Can Multiple Applications with different .net versions can run in same Server Machine

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, clr

Consider 3 application having .net version as 4 , 4.5 and 4.6.1
will they all can be hosted in same machine , If they are hosted in same server machine, Do they run on latest .net version OR their targeted version.what is CLR version , do we need to consider CLR version or Framework version.

Comment: @Austin - except the 4.6.1 is an in-place upgrade of 4.5, as is the same for 4.0

Comment: Right, so there's one single runtime, for 4.6.1. Not "runtimes".

Comment: generally It will have only the latest run time right and all these application run on it RIGHT!!!

Comment: if they are all targeting different versions, will they all run on same run time or different run times

Comment: what happens if the .net framework is out of support , do they automatically change runtime version

Comment: @Austin try not to mislead here. I will leave an answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple versions of .NET on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164607/multiple-versions-of-net-on-the-same-server)

Comment: Under normal circumstances, we mainly consider the framework version, because CLR is a part of framework. The image shows the version relationship between CLR and framework. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwl4e.png

Answer (score 0):

While [Multiple versions of .NET on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164607/multiple-versions-of-net-on-the-same-server) answered many general parts of running different .NET versions on a single machine, your question is more related to .NET Framework 4.x in-place upgrade so it's kind of on its own.

You should know that the three web apps you referred to in "3 application having .net version as 4 , 4.5 and 4.6.1" are bind to each of the .NET Framework versions at compile time. When such apps are deployed to a Windows machine, they are hosted by a single runtime, the actual .NET Framework installed on that machine (likely to be .NET Framework 4.7.x or 4.8 on a modern machine). Since it's a single .NET Framework, you also only see a single CLR version.

Overall, in your case you don't have to worry too much, and just select the right runtime in IIS application pool settings. You only need to worry and learn more about side by side when you have web apps with older .NET Framework versions or .NET Core.

.NET Framework does have a lifecycle and can retire, which you can learn from Microsoft's dedicated articles. I wrote a summary earlier this year when the policies experienced some huge changes, https://blog.lextudio.com/dotnet-framework-lifecycle-changes/ On your hosting machine, you have to upgrade to a supported version, or things are going to break.